# java make image resize with containing panel

Tags: java, image, autoresize, resizable

I have a panel with a label that contains an image.

I know how to resize the image, but I would like to trigger the resizing automatically when the containing panel in resized - to keep roughly the same relative size.

Where should I put the call to my resizing function?

```
    public JPanel slidePane;
    public JLabel iconLbl;

    iconLbl = new JLabel();
    iconLbl.setIcon(getImage(slides.get(0),this));
    iconLbl.setA lignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    slidePane.add(iconLbl);
```

//

```
    public static ImageIcon getImage(String ImageName, SlideShow ss) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = ss.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(ImageName);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon( imgURL);     
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Width: " + image.getIconWidth() + " Height: " + image.getIconHeight());
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
        image.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
        g.dispose();
        BufferedImage resizedimage;

        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SIZING: "+ss.starterModule.Tabs.getWidth()+" "+ ss.starterModule.Tabs.getWidth());
            resizedimage = myResize(bi,ss.starterModule.Tabs.getWidth(), ss.starterModule.Tabs.getWidth());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            resizedimage=myResize(bi,600, 700);
        }
        ImageIcon resizedicon=new ImageIcon(resizedimage);

        return resizedicon;

    }

    public static BufferedImage myResize(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return bi;
    }
```

Comment: Typically you would use a layoutmanager to do this for you.  Try using a GUI builder such as NetBeans or Eclipse to build your forms.

Answer (score 0):

Use a layout manager like this:

```
iconLbl = new JLabel() {
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(...);
  }
}
sidePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
sidePanel.add(iconLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

There are different layout managers, but if it gets too complex I recommend a GUI builder like those found in NetBeans or Eclipse.

The drawImage() function can scale the image on the fly as needed so you don't need myResize().  See Graphics.drawImage() for parameters.

Comment: I think this is not that kind of issue. The label itself maybe be resized, but not the Icon

Comment: ya, second thought, layout mgr will not resize the icon (but still needed).  Next you need to override paintComponent() in JLabel and resize the image before painting it.